# Delete All Chips At once Jquery and css

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I am using CSS chips for my project. For now its working fine for adding new chips and remove chips one by one. How can I modify my code to remove all existing chips at once?

```
<div id="basic" class="section scrollspy">
  <button class="myBTN">Add New</button>
  <button class="myBTN2">Delete All</button>
  <div class="input-field">    
    <div id="Filter" class="chips chips-autocomplete chips-placeholder"></div>
  </div>
</div>


$(function() {

  var x = 1;
  $(".myBTN").on("click",function(e){
    var text = $(this).text()+x;
    x++;
    var e = jQuery.Event("keydown");
    e.which = 13; // # Some key code value
    $(".chips input").val(text);
    $(".chips input").trigger(e);
  });

  $(".myBTN2").on("click",function(e){     
  });

  $('.chips-placeholder').material_chip({
    placeholder: 'Enter a tag',
    secondaryPlaceholder: '+Tag',
  });

  $('.chips').material_chip();
});
```

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/q7ovaj4L/3/)

Comment: $(".myBTN2").on("click",function(e){ $('.chip').remove();})

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can just trigger a click on their close button

```
$(".myBTN2").on("click",function(e){
    $('.chip .close').click();
});
```

https://jsfiddle.net/2fu3r17d/

Answer (score 2):

You can do it using .remove()

```
$(".myBTN2").on("click",function(e){
    $(".chips .chip").remove();
});
```

https://jsfiddle.net/zLjg4d0s/

Answer (score 1):

Find `div` inside `customerFilter` and remove.

```
 $(".myBTN2").on("click", function(e) {
    $('#customerFilter').find('div').remove();
});
```

[Fiddle Link](https://jsfiddle.net/ofr3pu54/)

Answer (score 1):

Just select all .chip divs inside #customerFilter and remove it.

```
$(".myBTN2").on("click",function(e){
  $('#customerFilter .chip').remove();  
});
```